# Нужно неизвестное число n перевести в двоичную систему в JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно неизвестное число n перевести в двоичную систему, используя только циклы

```js
function testCycle(n) { //задается число n
    x = ''; 
    for(i = n; i > 0; i = i / 2) { //пока n не будет равна 0, будет делиться на два
        x = (i % 2) + ''; //получаем остаток и прибавляем
        Math.trunc(i); // округлить
    }
    return x; // вывод
}
```

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: нужно число n перевести в двоичную систему, а в коду какая то ошибка

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что в коде ошибка?

Comment: Ответ не соответствует

Comment: откуда ты взял этот код? Ты можешь прокомментировать каждую строку, указав что в ней происходит?

Comment: хорошо, сию минуту

Comment: Отличные комменты

Comment: я просто только изучаю js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в двух строках:

```
x = (i % 2) + ''; //получаем остаток и прибавляем
Math.trunc(i); // округлить
```

На каждой итерации переменная `x` перезаписывается. Вместо `''` нужно было использовать саму переменную `x`, тогда и описание бы оказалось верным

```
x = (i % 2) + x; //получаем остаток и прибавляем к `x`
```

Строчка с округлением бесполезна, так как результат округления никуда не присваивается.

Вместо этого места, округление (отбрасывание дробной части) нужно было производить в третьей секции `for` где описывается следующее значение `i`

```
i = Math.trunc(i / 2)
```

В итоге можно получить следующее:

```js
function testCycle(n) {
  x = '';
  for (i = n; i > 0; i = Math.trunc(i / 2)) {
    x = (i % 2) + x;
  }
  return x;
}

console.log(testCycle(7));
console.log(testCycle(12));
console.log(testCycle(22));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я думал, что не решу это сегодня